# Extracting arguments in IIS rewrite - where am I going wrong?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

How can I redirect '/path?foo=abc&bar=def' to '/path/abc/def'?

I've tried the following:

```
<rule name="My rule" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^path" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="foo=/[^&amp;]*/" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="bar=(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/path/{C:0}/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

But this doesn't even process my match. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to a computer to verify this, but I think the following could simplify:

```
<rule name="Redirect old FAQ view" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^path.*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^foo=([^&]*).*?bar=(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/path/{C:0}/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

You don't need the second input line as you can use multiple capturing groups in one. I'm not sure if the whole line will come back as a match or not so you may need to adjust to `{C:1}/{C:2}`. Finally, I'm not sure if the match url was problematic. It would contain the query string as well, so that may have been causing it to miss. Look [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule) for more details on the various components of the URL rewrite process.

Comment: With a couple of minor corrections (now reflected in your answer), this worked perfectly. Most impressive without a computer - thank you!